# Sales Grid - total_invoice vs. total_paid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

What is the difference between "total_invoice" vs. "total_paid"?

I looked here (dev docs)
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html

Also, dev docs descriptions are completely useless in this case.

Does this mean that someone can be "invoiced" not a full amount?  Or does it mean that someone has been invoiced but not yet paid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have invoices that are not paid.
The grand total of the invoice is added to the total paid field if the order when the invoice is paid.
Check the [`pay` method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php#L407) in the invoice model.
It contains this

```
    $this->getOrder()->setTotalPaid(
        $this->getOrder()->getTotalPaid()+$this->getGrandTotal()
    );
    $this->getOrder()->setBaseTotalPaid(
        $this->getOrder()->getBaseTotalPaid()+$this->getBaseGrandTotal()
    );
```

The code above adds the grand total of the invoice to the total sum paid of the order.
Also, when an invoice is canceled the grand total of the invoice is subtracted from the total paid.
Check the [`cancel` method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php#L458)  from the same invoice model.

```
    if ($this->getState() == self::STATE_PAID) {
        $this->getOrder()->setTotalPaid($this->getOrder()->getTotalPaid()-$this->getGrandTotal());
        $this->getOrder()->setBaseTotalPaid($this->getOrder()->getBaseTotalPaid()-$this->getBaseGrandTotal());
    }
```